# Problem with sans serif font in Komascript

Tags: fonts, koma-script

I want to make a complex, custom titlepage with graphics etc. (I don't see that using the default template is an option). I want to use the "TeX Gyre Pagella" serif font (-> http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/tgpagella/) for the "normal" text and a sans serif font for the title page (maybe also for chapter, section names etc.).

If I load the Gyre Pagella font a sans serif version of this font is also loaded, right? The problem is that I want the title text bold and in sans serif but it doesn't work (I can't get it bold). Is such a case not "defined" in the font definition file? Is it possible to use another sans serif font in Komascript?

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\vspace{5cm}
\textsf{
\textbf{\fontsize{30}{30}\selectfont A very long title}\\[2cm]
Mr. Author\\
\vspace{2cm}
2013
}
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\chapter{Some text using a serif font}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: The pagella font is based on Palatino, which was designed by Herrmann Zapf. Zapf didn't design a sans-serif font to "match" Palatino. There is to date no sans serif "version" of Palatino. You could try using Helvetica as the sans serif font; if you do so, look into scaling Helvetica down a bit, as its x-height is rather larger than that of Palatino.

Comment: @Mico Actually there _is_ a [Palatino Sans](http://www.linotype.com/3201/palatinosans.html). I was very surprised to see this.

Comment: @marczellm - wow, I stand corrected. I didn't know this font existed. However, since it's not in the LaTeX catalogue of fonts, the OP won't  be bake to use it unless she/he uses either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX and somehow (likely through a purchase...) has access to the font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The font `TeX Gyre Pagella` is based on `Palatino`, which was designed by Herrmann Zapf. Within the past ten years or so, Zapf has designed a sans-serif font, called `Palatino Sans`, to accompany `Palatino`. Note, though, that `Palatino Sans` isn't free and isn't include in any of the standard TeX distributions.

You may want to use `Helvetica` as your document's sans serif font. If you do so, you should probably look into scaling `Helvetica` down a bit as its x-height is rather larger than that of `Palatino`.